# What's the best way to listen key hold, key press and key release events without pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I need a simple joy stick for my raspberry robot. PyGame doesn't work properly in my IDE, eclipse or putty, because of X-Server problems etc.

For this purpose I would like to write a minimalistic key event listener but I can't manage to make python listen the key release event with my code:

```
import sys, tty, termios, time

#Old settings
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

#Loop
work=0
while True:    
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)    
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)

    if "w" in ch and work==0:
        work=1
        print "Car goes"

    if "w" not in ch and work==1:
        work=0
        print "Car stops"

    if ch in "c":
        break
```

If I hold the key w down, it will be recognized. If I release it the loop waits for a new input.

Why and at which line does my loop wait for a key down? I would like to do this with a minimalistic code for the test purposes.

Answer (score 1):

your code stops at

```
ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
```

since it tries to read 1 character from stdin, but it have none so it just waits until there is one.

if you want to read from it in a non-blocking way, check this out:
https://repolinux.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/non-blocking-read-from-stdin-in-python/

as you can see, there are multiple ways to do so, but they are not quite simple